# Data integrity and recovery with Django and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, debian, signals

Django can be run either in Nginx (or some other server, but we are currently going to use Nginx) or with `manage.py runserver` Django own's server. In both cases I need data integrity and recovery.

For data integrity I need not to terminate (some of) Django requests until they finish. They should not terminate because they should finish started data modification in the DB to preserve data integrity (and no, using SQL transactions is *not* a solution). They should not terminate as soon as Nginx receives `service nginx stop` (on Debian Linux) or some other similar command (on other OSes), but finish processing before terminating. How to do this?

For data recovery I want:

1. create an empty file when the server starts, remove it when the server stops (how to do it both with Nginx and with `manage.py runserver`?)
2. When the server starts, if the file is found (indicating a crash of our software), before server starting we need to run my "data recovery" script. How to do this?

Comment: why transactions aren't an option? because of the use of django signals which need to process?

Comment: and which wsgi server actually runs behind nginx?

Comment: @dahrens Big writing transactions are not an option because they would cause delays for reading operations **for all our customers**.

Comment: not really - if you dig deeper into the topic of the (quite good) answer from @PopcornArsonist, you'll notice that wsgi servers came along with more than one process to handle requests. This solves the delay problems.

Comment: Delays would be caused not by the HTTP server or wsgi but by MySQL database which they use. Long transactions = delays

Answer (score 2):

A couple things here. First, you should definitely never use runserver in production. Secondly, you don't run really Django *in* nginx—you run it in a WSGI server, such as uWSGI or Gunicorn. Often, these are run *behind* nginx, but they don't start and stop when it does.

If you're just trying to make sure that the server doesn't stop while views are still processing, you could definitely do that with uWSGI. There's a pretty good writeup on this subject in the uWSGI documentation called ["The Art of Graceful Reloading"](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html).

As long as the server is gracefully reloaded, I don't think you need to worry as much about recovery. However, if you still wanted to try that, you'd need to do the empty file deletion in a bash script wrapper—there's no Python code that runs when the server stops.